# How to skip 'retake and use' option after captureing photo from camera

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera

[image]

How to skip 'retake and use' option after captureing photo from camera or how to change font and color of these buttons.

We have used following code

```
    self.gimgPicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
    self.gimgPicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(310, 310);
    self.gimgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.gimgPicker.desiredSize = CGSizeMake(640, 640);
    imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            // Set type to Photo Library if button at index is selected
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

                self.gimgPicker.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [parentController presentModalViewController:self.gimgPicker.imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this view is brought to you by [showsCameraControls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls) property of `UIImagePickerController` class

If you set it to `NO` you won't see that screen, but you will have to provide camera controls.

Your alternative is to use [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) which will give you full flexibility on how it looks and performs. Although it will take a bit more time to setup, it will pay-off in the long run.

Comment: To make it clearer, I found this Demo https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Creating-a-Custom-Camera-View Here's also the repo https://github.com/lteu/demo_AVFoundation

Answer (score 0):

I use swizzle to solve this problem, though a little bit hack...

Using reveal I know the shutter button's class name is CAMShutterButton, and it's a subclass of UIButton

So I just hide this button when it's loaded to superview, and put a custom shutter button to send takePicture message

Well since I can hide it, I can actually add target action to this button or using notificatio

remember to setShowsCameraControls before call takePicture to skip retake and use

[image: camera without shutter button]

then u can do what ever u want in

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Answer (score 0):

What about?

**imagepicker.allowsEditing = NO**